# EDIT - Get a full duplicate records filtered with an alternative to having

Tags: sql

I already made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923918/rails-select-all-fields-from-record-based-on-having-clause) this question on So in the Rails forum. I need to have a better clarification on sql part.
I want a select statement which returns all columns doing a filtering.
I did this statement:

```
select name, doc_num, id_user from A group by name, doc_num, id_user having count(*) > 1
```

When I did this I didn't know group by clause requires all columns in which it uses must be the same on select statement.
Instead of having, is there another methos to filter results in the same way as having?

Comment: Huh? What do you mean? What is wrong with what you have here?

Comment: Tag your question only with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: @SeanLange I have the table A with 15 columns and I would like to get results with all columns instead the columns used  in group by

Comment: OK. Are you looking for "duplicate" rows? If you don't count all of the columns as part of the definition of a duplicate what do you plan to use?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, for duplicate rows. The issue is how can I have the same effects getting all columns in duplicate rows without having clause

Comment: You could use row_number. But if all columns are not the same they are not actually a duplicate so you need to define your logic. The best option by far is to provide sample data and desired results.